# spdlog logging a single wchar_t string containing data which inculdes {...}

Tags: c++, spdlog

I am using spdlog with a registry application. I am getting an exception when attempting to log a single wchar_t string containing a reprentation of a CLSID, say "{0C092C21-882C-11CF-A6BB-080C7B2D682}". I understand that in spdlog "{}" is a formatting parameter character pair and accept an exception should be thrown for the data above, but how do I log such data?

Answer (score 0):

You pass it as a parameter:

```
spdlog::error(L"{}", L"{0C092C21-882C-11CF-A6BB-080C7B2D682}");
```

You should do this in general for all input strings that aren't constant string literals whose content you know doesn't include format specifiers. Same applies to `printf` family of functions, except the format specifiers are different for them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping for a non-variadic solution. I wrap the spdlog in a class hopefully to aid swapping logging systems and support logging with utility member functions. At the point of failure/report/.. in the code I use wstringstream to build a error/debug/info/... message with all the local context information and use a single wstring parameter call to the log wrapper class.